# How do I make an SQL trigger that grabs the data that was passed into the query which activated the trigger?

Tags: mysql

I want to make it so when an entry is added to the `votes` table, whichever `user` the `message`/`comment` which was voted on gets an entry into their `total_votes`. I looked into [sql triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) and it seems like it is what I want, but I am not sure how to get the information from the vote the user is creating in order to lookup the correct `messageId` and thus find the user who posted that message.

```
CREATE TABLE marks (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  x float(10, 6),
  y float(10, 6),
  z float(10, 6),
  timestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  messageId int(5) NULL,
  commentId int(5) NULL,
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (commentId) REFERENCES comments(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (userToken) REFERENCES users(token)
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  messageString text,
  image varchar(255),
  score int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  commentString text,
  messageId int(5),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id)
);

CREATE TABLE votes (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  messageId int(5) NULL,
  commentId int(5) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userToken) REFERENCES users(token),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (commentId) REFERENCES comments(id),
  UNIQUE KEY (userToken, messageId),
  UNIQUE KEY (userToken, commentId)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  token VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(token),
  total_votes int(5)
);
```

Comment: in the trigger, just refer to `NEW.whatevervalue` to get the values being inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to the new values in a trigger with the `NEW.` prefix. ie if you insert into a row that contains the field `value`, that field is available in the trigger as `NEW.value`, from there it is simple to construct an `after insert` trigger for your votes table. something like this:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger vote_increment after insert on votes
for each row
begin
  update users set total_votes = total_votes + 1 where token = NEW.user_token;
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

[demo fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d32d3/1)

i'm not sure what your final logic needs to be, since you mention the messages table, and i don't see why that's necessary just to get the user to update their total, since the vote table contains `userToken`